# Removing from array and manage spaces after removing a worker

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, void, removeall

I have this method that removes a worker if his name starts with assigned letter accepted from the `removeWorker()` method. Can somebody explain how the second `for` loop is working?

```
public void removeWorker(String s) {
    if (index == 0) {
        System.out.println("There is any worker in array!");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (worker[i].getName().startsWith(s)) {
            for (int j = i; j < index - 1; j++) {
                worker[j] = worker[j + 1];
            }
            worker[--index] = null;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the index variable represent and were do you initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop moves all workers one place closer to the start of the array. This is done to avoid "holes" in the array (which would occur if you only set the element to `null`). This is what happens:

```
if(worker[i].getName().startsWith(s))
```

This checks if the worker with the index i should be removed.

```
    for(int j = i; j < index - 1; j++) 
    {
```

This for-loop iterates over all workers with an index greater or equal to i, hence starting with the worker to be removed. It stops with the second to last index, as it also accesses the worker with the index j + 1.

```
        worker[j] = worker[j + 1];
```

This here moves the worker with the index j + 1 to the position j. This overwrites the worker to be removed with the worker with the next higher index. All other workers are only shifted.

```
    }
    worker[--index] = null;
```

Here the last worker is set to null, as it was saved in the second to last position during the for loop. This ensures that the last worker is not in the array twice. Also the index (the number of workers) is decremented with `--index` as there is one worker less in the list.

```
    i--;
}
```

Now i is decremented as it already is the index of the next worker to check and the for loop will increment it again. Without this the worker after the worker just removed would not be checked.

Comment: Leon your description is very useful :)
Now i can understand this method .

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop moves all the remaining workers that are located after the one you removed one step down in the array, in order to avoid open spaces. This way the last one is duplicated, but that is fixed after the loop.